# Synchronize Oracle database to Access database

Tags: c#, oracle, ms-access, windows-services, software-design

My client application maintains Access database and most of time work offline. 
In server side there is a web service with Oracle back end. I need to update Access database row data tables with latest Oracle database table data. Currently I'm doing this by C# windows service which triggered by timer. Is there any alternative to achieve this data synchronization with fault tolerance and good performance. Please share your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)** (is a full-featured, open source job scheduling system that can be used from smallest apps to large scale enterprise systems.) to schedule synchronization.

Data base synchronization can be done using **[Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753)** but I'm not sure whether it support for Access database or not.